# Creating a link to pass a PHP venerable to jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I can not seam to be able to figure out why the code below is not adding the id to the jQuery script, I do know that the $value['expid'] has the value of 13 in it and it is my understanding that echoing this PHP code will make jQuery see the number that is in the venerable.

The leak that creates the data-id value grabbed by the jQuery script

```
<a href='#' class='open-editexpenses' data-target='#editexpenses' data-id='<?= htmlspecialchars($value['expid'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>'>Edit</a>
```

The jQuery script

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-editexpenses', function() {
              var id = $(this).data('data-id');
                alert(id);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "expmodal.php", 
                    data: {id: id},
                     success: function(html) {
                $('body').append(html);
                $('#editexpenses').modal('show');
}
                });



           });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(this).data('id')
```

Or

```
$(this).attr('data-id');
```

(The first is usually preferable)

Comment: Thank you !!!! It only took me 6 days to get this figurd out Guesse I was asking in the wrong place